# redirecting from one place to another

Tags: python, html, django, web

I have in the html file a button defined as ;

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="login_button" style="width: 109px; "/>
```

This button is on the sample.com . USer comes and clicking on the this button, then current web page, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample`,is changed to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample2`, defined on the login.html. For this reason, I have done ;

```
def auth(request):
  if 'login_button' in request.POST:
    // redirect the web page to the sample2.com
  return render_to_response('login.html', {} )
```

I have tried to `redirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample2`), but it is not worked. How can I go to another page.

Other web page defined on the this function

```
  def message(request):
          current_date_T = Template ("<p style=\"text-align: right;\">\
                                {{Date|truncatewords:\"8\"}}\
                            </p>")

          # --
          return HttpResponse(html)
```

url file

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
            ('^sample2/$', message),
            ('^sample/$', auth),
  )
```

page opened first is sample, in it there is a button. Sample2 will be called after button on the sample is clicked.

Comment: Have you tried with `return` statement? `return redirect("sample2.com)`

Comment: @AamirAdnan can you look at my edited question?

Comment: @AamirAdnan the last edit, I fixed my errors, can you helo me?

Comment: post your `urls.py` file content also where you have defined the sample2 url

Comment: @AamirAdnan look at edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all define names to your urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^sample2/$', message, name="message_view"),
    url('^sample/$', authentication, name="auth_view"),
)
```

Then use url reverse resolution technique to get the url of a view using name of url:

```
def auth(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        // redirect the web page to the sample2.com
        return redirect(reverse('message_view'))
    return render_to_response('login.html', {} )
```

I don't know what is the purpose of redirect here. But thats how it works.

Comment: In your code, which part is checking the button is pressed or not ?

Comment: If button is presed then the request method is `POST` not `GET`. So if `request.method == 'POST'` then it means button was pressed.

Comment: If there is a two-three button on the page, how can it detect the which one is clicked?

Comment: Then why you are using a form? Use simple href tag in template for each of your url: `<a href="{% url message_view %}">Go to Message View</a>`

Comment: By the way, your solution is also gives the same error `CSRF cookie not set.`

Comment: in template just after the `<form>` tag put `{% csrf_token %}` and `CSRF cookie not set` error will be gone

Comment: Have you added `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings files?

Comment: I have put as `<form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}` </form> . I think I put it in correct place, am I ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23884/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-user2017495)

Answer (score 2):

you simply need [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead of `render_to_response`. Try the following:

```
def auth(request):
    if 'login_button' in request.POST:
        # redirect the web page to the /sample2
        return redirect('/sample2/')
    else:
        # Do something else
```